# jquery Get All Form Values and Ajax post like php array with mulitple elements with same name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a Form that has multiple inputs and select boxes such as

```
  <select name="id_prod_cat_main_addition[addons][11][16]">
  <select name="id_prod_cat_main_addition[addons][11][17]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="id_prod_cat_seperate[13][selected]" value="1">
  <select name="id_prod_cat_seperate[13][quantity]">

  <input type="checkbox" name="id_prod_cat_seperate[14][selected]" value="1">
  <select name="id_prod_cat_seperate[14][quantity]">

  <input type="checkbox" name="id_prod_cat_seperate[15][selected]" value="1">
  <select name="id_prod_cat_seperate[15][quantity]">
```

So when i submit my form on the back end i get the following formatted data

```
   [id_prod_cat_main_addition] => Array
    (
        [addons] => Array
            (
                [11] => Array
                    (
                        [16] => 2
                        [17] => 8
                    )

                [12] => Array
                    (
                        [18] => No Additional Drivers
                    )

            )

    )

   [id_prod_cat_seperate] => Array
    (
        [13] => Array
            (
                [selected] => 1
                [quantity] => 7
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [selected] => 1
                [quantity] => 9
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [quantity] => 1
            )

    )
```

Now what im trying to accomplish is with jquery anytime they make a change to any one of these select boxes im trying to post the same data in the same format via ajax to get up to date pricing to reflect on the front end prior to submitting the form

I tried the following

```
     function calculate_price()
        {
            var datastring = $("#products_form").serializeArray();
            var postData = JSON.stringify(datastring);
                console.log(postData);
           
            $.ajax({
                url: "/enrollment/pricing",
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: postData,
                success: function (results) { 

                }                
            });

            
        }
```

But the format for .serializeArray() is not even close to what im looking for. Does anyone know how to retrieve the form data in the same format as what php gets it in the back end when the actual form is submitted?

Comment: All you need is `var postData = $('#products_form').serialize()`. See https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: iv tried that - just gives me a string with all the info but even then im unable to break it up to make it similar to above

Comment: You don't need to break it up. If you POST that to PHP, you'll get the array you're after in `$_POST`, just like if the form submitted normally

Comment: oh shit your right :) thank you so much - i tried that originally and only paid attention to whats sent in the browser console but never cared to look on the backend to see